# iphone to ipad xib file change

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have the two xib files 1.main 2.language translator this is a iphone app.
  I want to change UNIVERSAL APP. i upgrade the universal application. now automatically created mainwindow-ipad.xib. 
         i run this app in xcode 3.2 version but it display left corner only . 
      how can i change this app to universal ... its big headache to me.. anyone help me

Thanks in advance,
Suresh.m

Answer (score 0):

Check whether app is on iPhone or on iPad and accordingly load the nibs, I mean  u have to keep the Ipad versions of ur interface builder files and load them according to the target device

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]interfaceIdiom]== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
 //Load ur ipad nib file
}
else
{
 //Load ur iphone nib file
}
```

Comment: thanks bharat it's working perfectltly..... I make another one change info-list to add the Main nib file base name (iPad) Main nib file base name (iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a new universal project, and then "move" my code into the template provided.  I find that much easier then trying to flip all the other knobs.

I found iphone_bharat's example interesting, but it has a small type so I had to fix it and clean it up a little bit.

```
+ (bool)iPad
{
    // Can use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() for iOS less than 3.2
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```